# To unset a javascript file in contao

Tags: javascript, concatenation, contao

I have got a javascript file which is in core folder and I want to unset that file without editing the core. I haved added

```
 $GLOBALS['TL_JAVASCRIPT'][] = 'system/modules/lazy-images/assets/lazysizes-gh-pages/lazysizes.min.js|static';
```

in my template file. And this file got minimized and is present in assets folder. But the same file is present in head tag.

```
<script src="system/modules/lazy-images/assets/lazysizes-gh-pages/lazysizes.min.js" async></script>
```

I need to unset this file. How this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This JavaScript is added via the `config.php` of that extension. See https://github.com/derhaeuptling/contao-lazy-images/blob/2.0.1/config/config.php

To unset it, you would simply need to search for `'system/modules/lazy-images/assets/lazysizes-gh-pages/lazysizes.min.js|async'` within `$GLOBALS['TL_JAVASCRIPT']` within the `config.php` of your own extension (wich is loaded *after* the `lazy-images` extension) and unset that array key.

However, it's probably not wise to do that. You should not combine this script with the others.

Comment: Worked in this way. But as you told, it is not the right method.